# Using possibility to move constant reference

Tags: c++, string, c++11, move, move-semantics

```
void foo (const std::string& str)
{
   std::string local = std::move(str);
}
```

I'm really confused that this is allowed. Am I missing something and in some cases it can be used? Like if I know that it's safe to move this string, should I still use this construction, or is it something that is allowed by the compiler but in real life it should be never used?

Comment: Moving const objects would do ... copy.

Comment: `std::move(str)` would result in `const std::string&&`, and the better constructor for it is the copy constructor.

Comment: So moving `const` objects should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is allowed in a sense that this code is syntactically correct. `std::move` is nothing but a glorified cast, which takes type of the argument into account when casting. If your argument type is `const &`, the object is casted to the same `const &&`, and when you call

```
std::string local = std::move(str);
```

you end up calling copy constructor of the `std::string`, since it is the only suitable overload (`std::string::string(string&& )` is not a viable candidate).

In the end, your `move` does exactly nothing, and can be seen as syntactic noise added to the code.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I missing something and in some cases it can be used?

It can be used in all cases where you can use:

```
std::string local = str;
```

This is effectively the same.

> should I still use this construction

No. Doing this would be pointless and confusing.

In a more complex example, where the type is templated and may be const or non-const, this makes sense. That way you can copy from const and move from non-const

> Like if I know that it's safe to move this string

You aren't moving the string. You cannot move from const xvalues.

If you know that it's safe to move a string, then pass an rvalue reference to non-const.